# I have created a small program that it works as standalone. However when used as a function returns 'get IndexError: list index out of range'

Tags: python, string, list, function, printing

The followig part of code give an error if i use it in a function

```
def print_first_data(Data_list):
    for i in range (0,len(Data_list)):
        print(Data_list[i][0],end="")
```

- Data_list is a two dimension list eg [["Marios",39],["Alice",28]...

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you please [edit] to include a [mcve] including: how are you calling the function after it's defined, and what is the full error traceback

Comment: I ran this function with the input you specified, and it printed "MariosAlice" with no error. I suspect if you debug it properly, the bad input will be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely due to **Data_list[i][0]** when **Data_list[i]** doesn't have any elements. You can add a check to ensure that each element of **Data_list** has at least one item before trying to access it.

Before accessing **Data_list[i][0]**, we check **if Data_list[i]** has at least one item using **len(Data_list[i]) > 0**. This condition prevents the **"IndexError"** by ensuring that the index is within the valid range of the list.

```
def print_first_data(Data_list):
    for i in range(len(Data_list)):
        if len(Data_list[i]) > 0:
            print(Data_list[i][0], end="")
```